# Find difference between two fields as columns in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql below

```
SELECT
ttstudent.ttstudentid,
ttstudent.studentid,
ttstudent.subjectid,
ttstudent.classnumber,
ttstudent.classid,
concat(student.fn, " ", student.sn) AS Student,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Feb7" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr7 Feb`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Jul7" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr7 July`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Feb8" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr8 Feb`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Jul8" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr8 July`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Feb9" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr9 Feb`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Jul9" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr9 July`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Feb10" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr10 Feb`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Jul10" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr10 Aug`,
ondemand.Student_ID
FROM ttstudent
INNER JOIN student ON ttstudent.studentid = student.code
INNER JOIN ondemand ON ttstudent.studentid = ondemand.Student_ID
GROUP BY ondemand.Student_ID
```

This generates for about 25 people a columnar list with the last column the calculated field that finds the difference between the last 2 values in the table. The scores are time stamped.

```
CODE |Year7Feb|Year7Jul|Year8Feb|Year8Jul|Year9Feb|Year9Jul| Year10Feb| Growth
abe1 |    2.3 |   2.9  |        |        |        |        |          |   .6
bas1 |        |        |   3.5  |   3.7  |        |        |          |   .2
cod  |        |        |        |        |        |  4.5   |    5.2   |   .7
```

What I would like to do is a add another column which would take the last two scores from each user (whichever column it is in) and find the difference. I would call this column growth.

I am struggling with what to use other than max. Any ideas?

Comment: which database server r u using, Mysql or SQL Server

Comment: In `ondemand` you have basically all the information together. Unfortunately the column `cycle` does not lend itself very easily towards sorting by date. Maybe you should think of reformatting that column into datetime or use strings like '2010-07' to denote the cycle. These values can then be sorted in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

Calculate column `growth` with the following query

```
SELECT si,ty,la.uid laid,pr.uid prid,(la.score-pr.score) growth FROM ( 
 SELECT si,ty,max(test_date) cyprev, cylast FROM ondemand INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Student_ID si,type ty,max(test_date) cylast FROM ondemand
         GROUP BY Student_ID,type
 ) od ON si=Student_ID AND ty=type AND cylast>test_date
 GROUP BY si,ty, cylast
) getlast2 
INNER JOIN ondemand la ON la.Student_Id=si AND la.type=ty AND la.test_date=cylast
INNER JOIN ondemand pr ON pr.Student_Id=si AND pr.type=ty AND pr.test_date=cyprev
```

and then `LEFT JOIN` it to your overall query (slightly simplified version here):

```
SET @subj:="Numeracy";
SELECT Student_id,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Feb7" and ondemand.type=@subj, ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr7 Feb`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Jul7" and ondemand.type=@subj, ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr7 July`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Feb8" and ondemand.type=@subj, ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr8 Feb`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Jul8" and ondemand.type=@subj, ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr8 July`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Feb9" and ondemand.type=@subj, ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr9 Feb`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Jul9" and ondemand.type=@subj, ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr9 July`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Feb10" and ondemand.type=@subj, ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr10 Feb`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Jul10" and ondemand.type=@subj, ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr10 Aug`,
growth
FROM ondemand LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT si,ty,la.uid laid,pr.uid prid,(la.score-pr.score) growth FROM ( 
  SELECT si,ty,max(test_date) cyprev, cylast FROM ondemand INNER JOIN (
   SELECT Student_ID si,type ty,max(test_date) cylast FROM ondemand
          GROUP BY Student_ID,type
  ) od ON si=Student_ID AND ty=type AND cylast>test_date
  GROUP BY si,ty, cylast
 ) getlast2 
 INNER JOIN ondemand la ON la.Student_Id=si AND la.type=ty AND la.test_date=cylast
 INNER JOIN ondemand pr ON pr.Student_Id=si AND pr.type=ty AND pr.test_date=cyprev
) gt ON si=Student_id AND ty=@subj  
GROUP BY Student_id;
```

I left out the `JOIN`s to tables `student` and `ttstudent`and their columns

```
ttstudent.ttstudentid,
ttstudent.studentid,
ttstudent.subjectid,
ttstudent.classnumber,
ttstudent.classid,
concat(student.fn, " ", student.sn) AS Student
```

**Edit:**

Just made the changes using your `test_date` column. The subquery was tested in MySQL, I hope it also works in your database.

**Edit2:**

I slowly see where you are coming from. It's getting more and more complicated (just filled in the xtra conditions concerning `type="Numeracy"` ... Maybe there is an easier solution after all?

Anyway, here is a **[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96045/9)** to demonstrate the whole thing (and here a modified version: [sqlfiddle2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d54a5/3)).

**3rd and final edit:**

What you *probably* want is something on the lines of [SQLfiddle3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96045/13) (--> only *one* SELECT command without a preceding `SET` statement). Your *complete command* should then look something like this:

```
SELECT
ttstudent.ttstudentid,
ttstudent.studentid,
ttstudent.subjectid,
ttstudent.classnumber,
ttstudent.classid,
concat(student.fn, " ", student.sn) AS Student,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Feb7" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr7 Feb`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Jul7" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr7 July`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Feb8" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr8 Feb`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Jul8" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr8 July`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Feb9" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr9 Feb`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Jul9" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr9 July`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Feb10" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr10 Feb`,
SUM(If(ondemand.cycle="Jul10" and ondemand.type="Numeracy", ondemand.Score, NULL)) AS `Yr10 Aug`,
ondemand.Student_ID,
getdif.growth
FROM ttstudent
INNER JOIN student ON ttstudent.studentid = student.code
INNER JOIN ondemand ON ttstudent.studentid = ondemand.Student_ID
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT si,ty,la.uid laid,pr.uid prid,(la.score-pr.score) growth FROM ( 
  SELECT si,ty,max(test_date) cyprev, cylast FROM ondemand INNER JOIN (
   SELECT Student_ID si,type ty,max(test_date) cylast FROM ondemand
          GROUP BY Student_ID,type
  ) od ON si=Student_ID AND ty=type AND cylast>test_date
  GROUP BY si,ty, cylast
 ) getlast2 
 INNER JOIN ondemand la ON la.Student_ID=si AND la.type=ty AND la.test_date=cylast
 INNER JOIN ondemand pr ON pr.Student_ID=si AND pr.type=ty AND pr.test_date=cyprev
) getdif ON si=ondemand.Student_ID AND ty=ondemand.type
WHERE ondemand.type='Numeracy'
GROUP BY ondemand.Student_ID
```

My previous versions reflected my personal preference of avoiding any kind of redundancy and also my ambition to parameterize things as much as possible. But I probably went a bit too far ;-).

Comment: The scores are timestamped using a field in ondemand called test_date in the format "2013-02-06 11:52:32" it is MYSQL server and I am using Navicat Thanks

Comment: This is not working working for me I get errors or when using the SET command at start get a mysql syntax error.

Comment: I assume that you are sending the SQL command from PHP using something like `mysqli_query()` or `pdo->query()`. In any case, you can only ever send **one** SQL command per call, so you will have to split the above SQL command into **two** PHP function calls, first the `SET ...`and then the large `SELECT` command. As they are both being sent from the same PHP file, the defined SQL variable will not have lost its scope in between.

Comment: Is there another way of doing this that is easier because the package I am building this in has one sql query. Can the call for numeracy be in the original sql? It is a static value and won't change within the query. How can this query work without using the set?

Comment: Yes of course! I only put it in for my own testing and flexibiliy really - just replace it with the string `Numeracy`again.

Comment: Problem is it errors when I put the entire code in. Says what my edit to your post says. Can you possibly put the entire sql statement up without the set command? Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Beutiful - works great needed to replace la.uid with la.student_id and pr.uid with pr.student_id. Many thanks for your help.